# Telerik Tab Strip... really this hard?

Tags: asp.net, xml, telerik

I'm using a tab strip in my project, which I know should be a five minute item but I can't get it to work.  All I ever see is the first pageview.  The tabs don't respond and the pageviews don't change.  I used these a while back and don't recall it being such a horror.

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" >

        <AjaxSettings>

            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadMultiPage1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMultiPage1" />

                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTabStrip1" />

                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>

            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadTabStrip1" >

                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMultiPage1" /> 

                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTabStrip1" />
                </UpdatedControls>

            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>   

    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

          <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" 
                MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" PageViewID="RadPageView1" Text="A" >
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" PageViewID="RadPageView2" Text="B">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                 <telerik:RadTab runat="server" PageViewID="RadPageView" Text="C">
                </telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
            </telerik:RadTabStrip>      
            <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">     
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Width="100%" >` 
    CONTENT HERE
    </telerik:RadPageView>

       <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%">`
    CONTENT HERE
    </telerik:RadPageView>
     <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView3" runat="server" Width="100%">`
    CONTENT HERE
    </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure I need to take a break but this is too exasperating.

Comment: If you comment out RadAjaxManager, does it work without Ajax?

Comment: @Win... Nope, making me totally nuts

Comment: I only see the third tab has a wrong PageViewID value (should be RadPageView3), but you don't even need the PageViewID attributes in such a simple setup. Otherwise, this should be OK. Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: @rdmptn ... None.  I just tore it all out and started from a clean page.  Seems to work ok. I get the feeling these are rather touchy.

Comment: Hasn't happened to me before...probably something got cached in the browser or in the ASP temporary files, idk...Glad to hear you have this working now

Comment: @rdmptn Thank you... appreciate the time spent on your suggestions. ^5